# Redirect to Home after Login on React Redux Application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am learning React Redux with Create-React-App

I am having trouble with the logic of stores, reducers, actions ect.

I have a simple login page (some JSX omitted to make it simpler to read)

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Logo from "../img/image-center.png";
import "./login.css";


class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errorMsg : ""
    };
    this.loginClicked = this.loginClicked.bind(this);   
    console.log("loggedIn:", this.props.login);
  }

  loginClicked() {
    try {
      this.props.loginUser(this.refs.email.value, this.refs.password.value)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("thisprops", this.props);        
      });
    }
    catch(ex){
      this.state.errorMsg = "Unable to connect to server";
      console.log("error", ex);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="login-bg">
        <div className="container signForm">
            <div className="col s12 l6 login-form">
              <p className="center-align">Login to Trade Portal</p>
              <form>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field">
                    <input id="email" type="email" className="validate" ref="email" />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field">
                    <input id="password" type="password" className="validate" ref="password" />
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <button
                    className="btn waves-effect waves-light"
                    type="button"
                    name="action"
                    onClick={this.loginClicked}
                    >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                  <a href="/subcontractor" className="register">
                    Register here
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="row"><div style={{textAlign: "center", color:"red"}}>{this.props.login.message}</div></div>   

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps({login}){
  return { login } ;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Login);
```

As you can see the LoginClick fucntion calls a prop loginUser which is derived using connect (and actually calls my Action Login method)

actions\index.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_USER, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_FAILED } from "./types";


export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/Account/GetUser");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};

export const loginUser = (username, password) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post("/api/Account/Login", {username: username, password: password, persistant: false });
        const message = res.data ? "" : "Incorrect username or password";
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER, payload: { success: res.data, message: message } });
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.log("Login Failed:", ex);
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILED, payload: { success: false, message: "Unable to connect to authentication server" } });
    }
}
```

The above code calls my Server and logs in the user, when succesful it is read in the loginReducer.js

```
import { LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_FAILED } from "../actions/types";

export default function(state = null, action) {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER:      
      return { success: action.payload.success, message: action.payload.message };
      break;
    case LOGIN_FAILED:
      return { success: false, message: action.payload.message };
      break;
      default:
    return { success: false, message: ""};
  }
}
```

Now my question is where and how do I redirect the user on succeful Logging in to the home page? "/Home"

I am hoping I can do it in Login.js somewhere, as one day I may want to have 2 login routes (Ie If logging in from a header it may not redirect to home, but when logging in from Login.js it should log into home). Therefore I dont think this action should go in the Action or Reducer. But I am unsure how I can bind it in Login.js so when Login successfull, redirect

Comment: i would do this in a saga.   checkout redux-saga, i'm really glad i took that approach when learning redux. edit: looks like you tagged thunks, you could do this in a thunk as well.

Comment: yes tagged thunk because I use thunk.. but im mostly confused how I bind an action in my login.js file to redirect the user to the home page.. after the dispatch. I can bind messages in JSX easily, so that if I update the store, it updates the message, but how can I bind a function so when the login state updates to logged in, it redirects if on that page..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible ways-

**1-** Redirect from loginClicked method after successful login (inside .then), Like this:

```
loginClicked() {
    try {
      this.props.loginUser(this.refs.email.value, this.refs.password.value)
      .then(() => {
          this.props.history.push('/home');       
      });
    }
    catch(ex){
      this.state.errorMsg = "Unable to connect to server";
      console.log("error", ex);
    }
}
```

**2-** Or another option is put the check inside render method, whenever any change happens to store, it will re-render the component and if you find the `success == true` redirect to home page, Like this:

```
render(){

    if(this.props.success)
        return <Redirect to="/home" />

    return (....)
}
```

---

If you follow the first approach then you need to put the check inside `componentDidMount` method also, if user want to open login page after successful login, redirect to Home page. You are maintaining the login session by bool `success` check that bool value.

```
componentDidMount(){
   if(this.props.success) {
      this.props.history.push('/home');
   }
}
```

**Suggestion**:

Avoid using string refs, as per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)**:

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you’re currently using
>   this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

Comment: 2nd way is more accurate and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Redux-thunk will return out whatever you return from your thunk, meaning if you return a promise (which your are already doing because it's an `async` function), you can simply await it in Login.js and then perform the redirect.

Looks like you could simply modify `console.log("thisprops", this.props);` in Login.js that takes place after `loginUser` is called to perform the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the react lifecycle.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.login.success && nexProps.login.success !== this.props.login.success) {
     this.props.history.push('/home');
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just move in main function, it work

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductCard = ({ props,product, ...rest }) => {
const navigate = useNavigate();  // <-- MOVE HERE
return (
    <Card
  
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100%'
    }}
    {...rest}
  >
    <CardActionArea onClick={event => {navigate('app/service/'+product.serviceID)}}>
    
    <CardContent> ...
```